# TypeError: db.collection.createIndex is not a function in Search functionality for express project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Using the code below I get the error `TypeError: db.collection.createIndex is not a function`, which I want to use to implement the search functionality from this site: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/

Perhaps there is an alternative way to do search for MongoDB?

```
 app.post('/search', function(req, res) {
        var results = [];
        mongodb.MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            db.collection.createIndex( { Name: "text", Code: "text" } );
            var searcher = db.collection('Modules').find({
                $test: {
                    $search: "Bob",
                    $caseSensitive: false
                }
            });
            searcher.forEach(function(doc, err) {
                //assert.equal(null, err);
                results.push(doc);
            }, function() {
                db.close();
                res.json(results);
                console.log("SEARCH IS WORKING")
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: With the above workflow have you noticed you are always creating the index every time you make a connection? Also, [`createIndex`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#createIndex) is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check if the index exists first before creating it. Use the **[`indexExists`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#indexExists)** function to check this:

```
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    var collection = db.collection('Modules');
    collection.indexExists('Name_text_Code_text').then(function(indexExists){
        if(!indexExists)
            collection.createIndex( { Name: 'text', Code: 'text' } );
    }).then(function(result){
        collection.find({
            $test: {
                $search: "Bob",
                $caseSensitive: false
            }
        }).toArray();
    }).then(function(results) {
        db.close();
        res.json(results);
        console.log("SEARCH IS WORKING");
    });
});
```